# R applying growth rate backwards

Tags: r, zoo

I have a data with two different monthly series and a one year overlap

```
ts1 <- ts(cumsum(rnorm(120,.1,1)), start = 1995, frequency = 12)
ts2 <- ts(cumsum(rnorm(120,.2,1)), start = 2004, frequency = 12)
```

They do not have the same levels (there was a rebasing in 2004) but with the overlap one can use the monthly growth rate of the first one to back-project the second one until 1995.

I would like to create a variable ts_series which has the levels of ts2 after 2004 and then uses the monthly growth rates of ts1 to back-project it. I have several such series in a zoo object, so I can either use a zoo method or group them in list and use mapply.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach, using a simple linear regression on the overlapping bits to identify the relationship between the two series and then applying that model to the non-overlapping part of `ts1` to estimate earlier values of `ts2`. The last step gives you a new `ts` object that represents the predicted values of `ts2` for the non-overlapping period.

```
# Make the toy data
set.seed(1)
ts1 <- ts(cumsum(rnorm(120,.1,1)), start = 1995, frequency = 12)
ts2 <- ts(cumsum(rnorm(120,.2,1)), start = 2004, frequency = 12)
# Now do the estimation
x <- as.vector(window(ts1, start = c(2004,1), end = c(2004,12)))
y <- as.vector(window(ts2, start = c(2004,1), end = c(2004,12)))
tsmod <- lm(y ~ x)
ts2preds <- predict(tsmod, newdata = as.data.frame(window(ts1, start = c(1995,1), end = c(2003,12))))
ts2prior <- ts(data = ts2preds, start = c(1995, 1), end = c(2003, 12), frequency = 12)
```

If you want instead to backcast ts2 on its own, though, Rob Hyndman's got you covered with the `forecast()` function in his `forecast` package. Following [an example](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/backcasting/) from his blog:

```
library(forecast)
f <- frequency(ts2) # Identify the frequency of your ts
h <- (start(ts2)[1] - start(ts1)[1]) * f # Set the number of periods you want to backcast
revx <- ts(rev(ts2), frequency = f) # Reverse time in the series you want to backcast
ts2plus <- forecast(auto.arima(revx), h)  # Do the backcasting
# Reverse its elements
ts2plus$mean <- ts(rev(ts2plus$mean), end=tsp(ts2)[1] - 1/f, frequency=f)
ts2plus$upper <- ts2plus$upper[h:1,]
ts2plus$lower <- ts2plus$lower[h:1,]
ts2plus$x <- ts2 # Replace the reversed reference series in the prediction object with the original one
# Plot it
plot(ts2plus, xlim=c(tsp(ts2)[1]-h/f, tsp(ts2)[2]))
```

Here's the plot that produces:

[image]

And here's how the two series compare:

```
> cor(ts2plus$mean, ts2preds)
[1] 0.9760174
```

If your main goal is to get the best possible point predictions of those earlier values, you might consider running both versions and averaging their results. Then this becomes a very simple multi-model ensemble forecast (or backcast).